# Using constraints in Xcode how to make the font size to scale up with lable size

Tags: xcode, uilabel

I am scaling up the size of a label in the storyboard in Xcode and it works fine. The one problem i have is that the size of the label scales up for ipad but not the size of the font so it is a big box with tiny font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Autoshink. Find the autoshrink option in the attributes inspector. you can set it to minimum size or scale. Set the value below to a small value and then set your font size to a really large size. If it doesn't fit in the table it will shrink to fit the right size so it will be big for iPad and small for iPhone.

Comment: actually after i tested it a little more i found out that the label has disappeared

Comment: that might have to do with the lines setting at the top of the attributes inspector. What is your value for lines?

Comment: The value of lines is at 1